# How to extract date using Excel

Tags: excel, formula

In an Excel column, there is a data entry that reads '21 Years 10 Months 019 Days ago.' Given that today is the 1st of November 2023, how can I determine the exact date represented by this entry?

Not sure, I have tried date and other formulas.

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: Edit your question to show what you have tried and how they did not work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The pharse '21 Years 10 Months 019 Days ago.' is not a standard date format. So you may break it down to exact parts and extract the numbers. That will not be a simple function and needs to merge multiple calculations.

For example you can extract the years using **left** and **serach**. Let say this pharse is placed at A1 cell then:

`=VALUE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("Year",A1)-1))` will give you any number before word year.

in a same way:

`=VALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH(" Year",A1)+6,SEARCH(" Month",A1)-SEARCH(" Year",A1)-6))` will give you any number between words **Year** and **month**.

and:

`=VALUE(MID(A1, SEARCH(" Month", A1) + 7, SEARCH(" Days", A1) - SEARCH(" Month", A1) - 7))` will give you any numbers between **month** and **days**

having these values you can do standard calculations between TODAY() and that day considering the complex exceptions for leap years etc. In the simplest form something like this:

```
=TODAY() - (B1 * 365 + C1 * 30 + D1)
```

Comment: How leap years are factored in in this formula?

Comment: Leap year is not calculated here. This is the simplest way as an example. For each month need to specify the month length also special exceptions. @santhosha

Comment: is there a way to count leap year also?

Comment: Please refer my formula

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Little verbose though!

```
=LET(ly,SUM(IF(MOD(SEQUENCE(,21,CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),1)-1,-1),4)=0,1,0)),ty,CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),1),TODAY()-((365*(ty-ly))+(366*ly)+30*CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),3)+CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),5)))
```

Comment: Relative to today (30-Nov-2023), your formula seems to give an incorrect result: `21 years 10 months 019 days ago` => `19-Jan-2002`. I would think it should be closer to `11-Jan-2002`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to compare the results of this formula with your expected results, especially since both year and month can have a variable number of days.

In the formula below, your text string is in `A1`, and the date you are subtracting from is in `G1`.

Also, I have assumed that the in your string will always be subtracted. If that  is not the case, you can test the last word to see if the values should be added or subtracted and edit the formula accordingly.

**You** will need to test it and figure out any issues if it does not return the dates you expect.

***Formula edited for simplification***

```
=LET(
    split, TEXTSPLIT(A1, " "),
    ymd, FILTER(split, BYCOL(split, LAMBDA(arr, NOT(ISERR(-arr))))),
    y, INDEX(ymd, 1),
    m, y * 12 + INDEX(ymd, 2),
    d, INDEX(ymd, 3),
    EDATE($G$1, -m) - d
)
```

[image]

Comment: @ Ron- How does this formula account for leap years?

Comment: @santhosha Since Year and Month are imprecise measures, it all depends on how you define those. BTW, I have altered my formula to both simplify and use a somewhat definition, in line with how MS generally uses it.